# Enable Visual Studio Cordova Project support TypeScript EMCAScript 6

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, taco

I want to use async / await feature of TypeScript in VS2015 Cordova project. 
I modify "target": "es6" in tsconfig.json

The intellisense doesn't show any error, however, while building the project, it shows:

**Error TS1311  Build: Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.**

But I've already changed target to es6 in tsconfig.json

Where else should I config to make the build work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` files were not picked up for certain project types. Work has been done on this for TypeScript 1.8, [as you can read here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-support-for-tsconfigjson-in-visual-studio-2015):

> TypeScript 1.8 allows `tsconfig.json` files in all project types.

If you you [download the 1.8 beta from the announcement page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta.aspx) (or wait for 1.8 proper), your `tsconfig.json` options should be respected.

---

However, as you turn that functionality on, keep the following in mind:

> If you add a `tsconfig.json` file, TypeScript files that are not considered part of that context are not compiled.

So you probably want to make sure that all your project's files are accounted for in your `tsconfig.json`, whether explicitly or by utilizing the `"exclude"` field.